# Xpath help - select a node and ignore siblings

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

i have a problem with querying an xml and getting the correct values.
I have this xml file

```
<A id="a">
    <B id="b"></B>
    <C id="c1">
        <E id="e"></E>
        <F id="f1"></F>
        <F id="f2"></F>
        <F id="f3"></F>
        <G id="g"></G>
    </C>
    <C id="c2">
        <E id="e"></E>
        <F id="f1"></F>
        <F id="f2"></F>
        <F id="f3"></F>
        <G id="g"></G>
    </C>
    <C id="c3">
        <E id="e"></E>
        <F id="f1"></F>
        <F id="f2"></F>
        <F id="f3"></F>
        <G id="g"></G>
    </C>
    <D id="d"></D>
</A>
```

I want to make a query in C# that selects everything to f2 but ignoring the F siblings and C siblings.
I would like to get this as a result

```
<A id="a">
    <B id="b"></B>
    <C id="c2">
        <E id="e"></E>
        <F id="f2"></F>
        <G id="g"></G>
    </C>
    <D id="d"></D>
</A>
```

Any help with this would appreciated.

Comment: What you describe ( ignoring the F siblings ) isn't what you show in your desired results.   You could try XPath builder to experiment: http://www.bubasoft.net/product/xpath-builder

Comment: XPath can only select elements in it's actual structure (means if `<C>` tag contains 5 children, when you select using XPath like `\\C`, `<C>` element will be returned as it is, having 5 children). Changing XML structure is a job for XSLT

Comment: Of course what i meant was that i want to select a certain F element and get the complete xml and ignore all the siblings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need use Linq-To-Xml:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);

// Find the node you want to start the process on
XElement node = root.Descendants("F")
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == "f2"
                                    && (string)x.Parent.Attribute("id") == "c2");

// Then iteratively remove similar named nodes recursively up the tree
XElement parent = node.Parent;
while (parent != null)
{
    var list = parent.Elements(node.Name)
         .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") != (string)node.Attribute("id"))
         .ToList();
    list.ForEach(x => x.Remove());
    node = parent;
    parent = parent.Parent;
}

XElement result = root;
```

The result:

```
<A id="a">
  <B id="b"></B>
  <C id="c2">
    <E id="e"></E>
    <F id="f2"></F>
    <G id="g"></G>
  </C>
  <D id="d"></D>
</A>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for. Need to learn Linq more